# Sort products by volume

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I do catalog of goods. I need to sort by volume.

Item.order("title ASC")

```
"CASTROL" MAGNATEC (10W40) 1l
"CASTROL" MAGNATEC (10W40) 208l
"CASTROL" MAGNATEC (10W40) 4l
"CASTROL" MAGNATEC (10W40) 60l
"CASTROL" MAGNATEC (5W30) 1l
"CASTROL" MAGNATEC (5W30) 208l
"CASTROL" MAGNATEC (5W30) 4l
```

I need something like:

```
"CASTROL" MAGNATEC (10W40) 1l
"CASTROL" MAGNATEC (10W40) 4l
"CASTROL" MAGNATEC (10W40) 60l
"CASTROL" MAGNATEC (10W40) 208l
"CASTROL" MAGNATEC (5W30) 1l
"CASTROL" MAGNATEC (5W30) 4l
"CASTROL" MAGNATEC (5W30) 208l
```

How do I get this sorted?

Comment: Did my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can just write a query like this

```
Item.order("volume asc")
```

This will work too for older versions of Rails.

```
Item.find(:all, :order => "volume asc")
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess the last column is volume? s that even data from your database? in case it is, you would `Item.order(:volume)`.

for that to work volume needs to be a number field in the database. if it's not a number, make it so and do the formatting to 1l etc during render time.